# how to add hyperlink to text in dart

Tags: dart, dart-html

I am trying to add an anchor tag to the message I want to display but I am getting an error message. Am I not doing this right?

```
String browserRequirementsUrl = "https://test.testing.com";
var someText = new ParagraphElement()
  ..innerHtml = "Link can be found <a href=${url}>here</a>[1].";
```

But I get an error message saying

```
  html_dart2js.dart:3614 Removing disallowed attribute <A href="https://test.testing.com">
```

Any suggestions, how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

By default in `dart:html`, for security purposes, this is disallowed.

You can use the [`.setInnerHtml` method](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.2/dart-html/Element/setInnerHtml.html):

```
..setInnerHtml("Link can be found...", treeSanitizer: NodeTreeSanitizer.trusted);
```

Note that this can potentially be insecure (i.e. inject `<script>` tags and such), so you can always create a custom sanitizer or validator to only allow a subset of HTML tags (such as `<a>`).